# How to solve for steady state matrix symbolically?

Tags: matrices, markov-chains, stochastic-matrices

I'm trying to understand this solution to a question related finding the steady state matrix $s$ for a regular markov chain.

Specifically I'm having trouble understanding how my textbook got

$$
\left( \begin{matrix}s1\\s_2 \end{matrix}\right) = \left( \begin{matrix}2r \\r \end{matrix}\right)
$$

If the transition matrix $T$ is $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{2} & 1 \\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 \end{array} \right)$ and $Ts=s$, $(T-I)s=0$

The textbook reduced the augmented matrix $[(T-I)|0]$ and somehow got $
\left( \begin{matrix}s1\\s_2 \end{matrix}\right) = \left( \begin{matrix}2r \\r \end{matrix}\right)
$

I don't understand why this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find the steady-state vector $s = \begin{pmatrix} s_1 \\ s_2 \end{pmatrix}$ you need to solve a simple matrix equation
\begin{equation}
(T - I)s = 0.
\end{equation}
But
\begin{equation}
T - I = \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} & 1 \\ \frac{1}{2} & -1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
and, thus, you have a linear system
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
-s_1/2 + s_2 = 0; \\
s_1/2 - s_2 = 0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Hence, we obtain $s_1 = 2s_2$.

So, if you denote $r = s_2$ then vector $s = \begin{pmatrix} 2r \\ r \end{pmatrix}$ is a solution of the matrix equation for every real number $r$.

And finally, vector $s$ must satisfy the normalization constraint:
\begin{equation}
s_1 + s_2 = 1.
\end{equation}
Therefore, $2r + r = 1$, that is $r = 1/3$ and the steady-state vector is the following:
$$s = \begin{pmatrix} 2/3 \\ 1/3 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Is there a way to solve using only matrix operations?